# Spring boot actuator not showing when I use @ComponentScan

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

My application looks like below. In this configuration my application works (it is bootstrapped with the @ComponentScan).

Unfortunately then /actuator/health does not work. When I remove @ComponentScan then actuator works but my application does not work.

What do I need to configure to make both @ComponentScan and actuator work?

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {DistributionApp.class})
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but we need to see the project structure and configuration classes first. Or, it would be great to have this project shared on Github.

Comment: Unfortunately it is an internal project. So I can not share full code. One thing to note is that the business logic is in a separate project from the Main class. (I think this is why we need ComponentScan).

Answer (score 2):

I found the actual issue.

I had a class with:

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/")
```

This shadowed the /actuator endpoints. So they did not show up.
So the problem was not related to @ComponentScan but it only surfaced when my own classes were activated.